# Key auto assigned on sequential array using integer keys

Tags: php

I'm coming from C++ and learning PHP at the moment.

When using arrays with key assignment I noticed that if you add an element to the array without specifying the key it'll auto-assign it.

Is that undefined behavior or PHP handles that?

```
$var = array( 1 => "The", 2 => "Rabbit", 3 => "Hole" );
$var[] = "Goes"; //add elements without specifying the key
$var[] = "Down";

print_r($var);
```

will output:

```
Array ( [1] = The [2] = Rabbit [3] = Hole [4] = Goes [5] = Down )
```

By using char keys and adding without specifying the key it'll add to [0]

```
$var2 = array ( 'a' => "All", 'b' => "The", 'c' => "Single" );
$var2[] = "Ladies";
print_r($var2);
```

will output:

```
Array ( [a] = All [b] = The [c] = Single [0] = Ladies )
```

Comment: Definitely not _undefined_ http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: [It's not undefined.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) The manual specifically states `if no key is specified, the maximum of the existing integer indices is taken, and the new key will be that maximum value plus 1 (but at least 0). If no integer indices exist yet, the key will be 0 (zero).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is defined by the PHP specification. In case you insert a new element without specifying a key:

If the array **already contains** at least one **integer key**, the largest of these keys will be taken, **incremented**, and used as a new key upon insertion.

If the array **does not contain an integer key**, the automatically assigned key will be **0**.

See the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Answer (score 1):

Yes the key will be auto generated by PHP.

If you have max key of 10 the new elements will be 11, 12 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It is defined behavior. See the [PHP documentation for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> The key is optional. If it is not specified, PHP will use the increment of the largest previously used integer key.